# Programmatically set margin to ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I need to change margin of toolbar, which was made of ConstraintLayout, in different cases. I tried to do it in following way

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ConstraintLayout.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.MarginLayoutParams(newLayoutParams);
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
toolbar.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams);
```

but in second case                 `layoutParams.setMargins(16, 16, 16, 16);`
 it did not change. So, can someone give other way or point to the mistake. Thanks for spending time to my problem.

I tried to use                 `newLayoutParams.setMargins(54, 54, 54, 0);` this puts margin to left and right, but I still need to put margin on top of it.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Finally with help of @Aksh I found my mistake and solve my problem. If someone find it useful, I will put my code bellow

```
     ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
     newLayoutParams.topMargin = 0;
     newLayoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
     newLayoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
     toolbar.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams);
```

Comment: and if its not working its most probably because the layout is not connected with the parent `constraintSet.connect(testButton.id, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START)`

Comment: In case if you are using Kotli ,             var newLayoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(yourLayout.layoutParams)
            newLayoutParams.rightMargin = 16
            yourLayout.layoutParams = newLayoutParams

Comment: This solution works, but you have to use pixels instead of dp for the values. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56550964/3697107 below by 6rchid helped me.

Answer (score 19):

good way to add margin to a view in constraintlayout

```
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayoutId)
val marginTop = context.getDimension(10f)
constraintSet.setMargin(R.id.tv_user, ConstraintSet.TOP, marginTop)
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayoutId)

fun Context.getDimension(value: Float): Int {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, value, this.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
}
```

Comment: it is displayMetrics and not displayMetric

Answer (score 13):

I once modified a ConstraintLayout with a `ConstraintSet` to change the elements it got linked with. I also changed the margin within that process which is the last parameter of the `connect` method:

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(layout);
constraintSet.connect(
    R.id.layout_id, 
    ConstraintSet.START, 
    R.id.layout_id2, 
    ConstraintSet.END, 
    8);
constraintSet.applyTo(layout);
```

Maybe this gives you another hint to find a solution?

Comment: I do not why, but using `ConstraintSet` does not change anything

Comment: I am sorry, I have not tested it with a toolbar, just some TextView and ImageView.

Comment: Thanks I tired all the above solutions but margins were not set after applying the new constraints using the above code to the layout it worked

Comment: I finally found something that works. They key takeaways I have now is: copy parent constraintset and apply to same parent, connect layouts.

Answer (score 4):

You might wanna try

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = yourConstraintLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.topMargin = x;
//others shows up in suggestion
```

I haven't tried it though I believe it should work as ConstraintLayout is a ViewGroup.

Comment: Thank you it helped me to find my mistake

Answer (score 2):

For `layoutParams.setMargins(w, x, y, z)` the reason it's not changing is because you're most likely treating the values as Dp's rather than Px's, for which the method accepts.

To get Px from the Dp, you want to use:

`int pxValue = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());`