# ConstraintLayout layoutParams setMargin() notWorking

Tags: java, android

I have a Floating Action Button, whose position I want to change programmatically

```xml
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
   android:id="@+id/expandViewButton"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:visibility="visible"
   android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/coordinatorLayout1"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/coordinatorLayout1"
   app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
```

I used the following code to change position programmatically.

```java
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new 
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int left,right,top,bottom;
left=(int)MainActivity.device_width/2;
right=0;
top=(int) MainActivity.device_height-200;
bottom=0;
layoutParams.rightMargin=right;
layoutParams.topMargin=20;
layoutParams.leftMargin=left;
layoutParams.bottomMargin=bottom;
   
layoutParams.bottomToBottom=R.id.fb1;
layoutParams.startToStart=R.id.fb1;
```

However `layoutParams.rightMargin`, `layoutParams.topMargin`, `layoutParam.leftMargin` and `layoutParams.bottomMargin` seem not to be working. Kindly suggest me a solution.

Comment: @Jameido layoutParams.topMargin not working

Comment: It might helpful follow this link:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148129/programmatically-set-margin-to-constraintlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148129/programmatically-set-margin-to-constraintlayout)